# Unexpected behavior of SIGMA symbol in eulervm

Tags: fonts, math-mode, align, eulervm

Consider the following minimal example (which has to use `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \rm{text}  = 
  x_\sigma
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which yields the following:

[image].

Note the symbol which appears instead of the expected `\sigma` and the font used for `x`. By removing the `eulervm` package the result is as expected, namely:

[image].

Now, even more counterintuitive, if you comment out the first line in the `align`, namely `\rm{text}  =` leaving the `eulervm` package in place I get:

[image].

Obviously, as shown in the last example, `eulervm` can typeset a `\sigma` symbol as a subscript, but not when there's some text in front...?

**Can someone explain what is happening here?**

Comment: You are using improperly the obsolete command `\rm`: use `\mathrm{text}` instead. And never use `\rm`.

Comment: @egreg: It is a code I got from a collaborator... Can you put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commands such as `\rm` or `\bf` have been obsolete since the release of LaTeX2e, almost twenty years ago.

They are *declarations*, so they should be placed *inside* braces:

```
{\rm text}
```

The `\rm{text}` form declares `\rm` for the whole formula, which explains why the `x` and the `\sigma` are typeset wrongly.

Nevertheless, as I said, this is not recommended at all. Better use `\text`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \text{text} = 
  x_\sigma
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\text` you can use `\textrm` or `\mathrm` (it depends on what you're really wanting to do).

Don't use `align*` as a substitute of `equation*` (or `\[...\]`), but this is another matter.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder regarding `align*`. In the original code it was needed, and I wasn't sure whether or not it is part of the problem.